# ryanb / nested_form undefined method `link_to_remove' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a little problem with gem nested_form. I have:

```
class Factura < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :itemfacturas_attributes
 has_many :itemfacturas
 has_many :productos, :through => :itemfacturas
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :itemfacturas, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:descripcion].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

and the ItemFactura class

```
class Itemfactura < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :vu, :vt, :descripcion
 belongs_to :factura
 belongs_to :producto
```

I used the gem in the facturas/new view to add itemfacturas.

```
<%= f.fields_for :itemfacturas do |b| %>
        <%= render 'itemfacturas/itemfacturas', f: b %>
 <% end -%>
 <%= f.link_to_add "Agregar item", :itemfacturas %>
```

And the partial is:

```
<%= f.number_field :cantidad, :min => 0, :value => 1 %>
<%= f.text_field :descripcion, :class => "desc_autocomplete" %>
<%= f.text_field :vu %>
<%= f.text_field :vt %>
<%= f.hidden_field :producto_id%>
<%= f.link_to_remove "Eliminar" %>
```

But I have this error:

> NoMethodError in Facturas#new
>
> Showing
>   /Users/fabricioflores/desarrollo/facturacion/app/views/itemfacturas/_itemfacturas.html.erb
>   where line #7 raised:
>
> undefined method `link_to_remove' for

If I comment line that contains link_to_remove I have another error about link_to_add

I followed steps from https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form but it did't work. I'm using Rails 3.2.9 and nested_form (0.3.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I solved it. In the form of facturas/new I need to put

```
<%= nested_form_for @factura do |f| %>
```

This was the reason that can't find the link_to_add and link_to_remove, because is a different helper.